# Formatting bug: preview doesn't look the same as the published question or answer

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, markdown-preview

In answering a question earlier today, I used some funky formatting. While this formatting might not be the best way of doing things, there is still a bug where the preview question doesn't look the same as the published question. This is what I used:

```
export FOO=/bi
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd> returns:
export FOO=/bin

```
export FOO=/bin:/sb
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd> returns:
export FOO=/bin:/sbin

In the preview, it looks like this:

> [image]

But in the published question, well, it looks like what is above. On my screen, it looks like this:

> [image]

Feel free to edit the question and see the code for yourself. The bug here is that the preview (while typing the question) doesn't look the same as the submitted question (or answer, both have the same issue). In the preview, there are no extra lines, but once submitted there are 3 extra lines in each "segment".

Comment: About midway through, there's a closing `code` tag instead of an opening one. Probably relevant.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for catching that, changed it to what it should be (which was </code></pre><pre><code>), but the bug is still in place.